# OpenVPN and logs

Tags: openvpn

I have installed OpenVPN on a linux server and was wondering how I can see http/traffic logs from a user. I would like to see something like:
User A accessed google.com at 2022-02-02:10:10:10 - And if there is a way to see packets?

Is is possible to see these logs with OpenVPN?

I tried looking for logs under, but no luck:

/var/log/syslog

/var/log/openvpn.log

/var/log/messages

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can see packets by watching the network interface. Use `tcpdump` or wireshark on the VPN network interface (eg. `tun0`).

You're not going to be able to decode encrypted packets such as HTTPS (at least not without a MITM attack). You will be able to see unencrypted DNS queries, IP addresses, and ports though.